# In iOS, how to get the name of a UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

If I have reference to a `UIStoryboard` object, how do I get its name?

For example if I have

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let name = self.storyboard?.name // public .name property does not exist
        let name = self.storyboard?.value(forKey: "name") // private property access works
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the name publicly?  If not, why did Apple make this private?

Edit: Add use case

The app has multiple storyboards and there is navigation code that is able to navigate to a particular storyboard: `navigate(to storyboardName: String)`. This code always instantiates a new storyboard object and its initial view controller. This is causing bugs in the UI.

I want to do a check to see if the window's root view controller's storyboard is the same as the destination storyboard to prevent re-instantiation.

Comment: A storyboard doesn't have a name (and you shouldn't need to access it anyway). The "name" is just the file name that you give it. What is it you are trying to do...? because you should not need to access the storyboard name this way at all.

Comment: @Fogmeister Added what we're trying to do in the question.